# Where is my terminal?

Tags: neovim, terminal, terminal-buffer, plugin-ironnvim

I installed [iron.nvim](https://github.com/Vigemus/iron.nvim).

I open two Python files with `nvim m1.py m2.py`.

When I send over some lines to the REPL and then close the first buffer with `:bd`, I'm left with the terminal window.

I go to the second buffer with `:bn`.

But now where is my terminal?

How can I have it as a left vertical split as it was before?

**EDIT**

`<C-w>w` doesn't work to go back to the terminal as well.

Comment: I discovered it reappears if I call `:IronRepl`. Maybe iron hid it?

Comment: Ask at the plugins issue tracker